# How to manage passing a pointer to an array to a function

Tags: c++

I have a buffer of points that I want to send off to be processed by a function.  It is an array of unsigned shorts.  Currently I'm trying the following:

```
void ftn(unsigned short **buffer, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(buffer[i]) = 0; //test
    }
}
```

Outside of the function, it's defined as `unsigned short buffer[size];` Does this not make sense?  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks

Comment: related [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) on arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, you don't actually pass the array by value. Rather, you actually pass a reference to the original array.

Therefore, you simply need to do:

```
void ftn(unsigned short buffer[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0; //test
    }
}
```

Note that if you change the actual value of `buffer`, you don't actually change the original array. An example of this could be:

```
void ftn(unsigned short buffer[], int size)
{
    buffer = new unsigned short[20];
}
```

If you wish to change the original array, your construct will work, but with a little modification:

```
void ftn(unsigned short **buffer, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (*buffer)[i] = 0; //test
    }
}
```

This is very C-like, mind you, and less C++-like.

`buffer` is a pointer to a pointer to an `unsigned short`. (That is, a pointer to the variable you use to refer to the array.)

If you dereference `buffer`, you get a pointer to an `unsigned short`, which can be treated as an array of `unsigned short`s.

With this you also have the ability to reassign the value of the original variable, for instance like this:

```
void ftn(unsigned short **buffer, int size)
{
    *buffer = new unsigned short[20];
}
```

#### See also:

- [Arrays as parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

Comment: I think that this answer is still too abstract. What is actually happening is that a pointer is being passed by value. Consider `void ftn(unsigned short buffer[], int size) { buffer = new unsigned short[size * 2]; }` . Nothing is happening to the original array, the pointer parameter is just being reassigned; `buffer` isn't a reference to an array.

Comment: P: With respect to your edit, the call to the function would just pass the buffer and its size?  Trying to use your example of (*buffer)[i] leads to bad pointer references

Comment: @apple: Unless you need to allocate a new array instead of the old one, stick with the first version I gave. Remember, you can still change the values within the array in that version, it's only the array itself you cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't make sense, because buffer[i] "returns" an array of shorts, and the
*(buffer[i]) tries to dereference that array of shorts, and then, you try to set a memory address for that (i.e. NULL or 0), and that results in a seg fault.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but just for clarification, how does *(buffer[i]) try to dereference an array of shorts.  Shouldn't it be trying to dereference a single short in an array?  This is where my confusion stems from.

Comment: `*(buffer[i])` evaluates `buffer[i]` first, and then applies `*` to the result. `buffer[i]` means "treat `buffer` as an array and grab the `i`th element". You shouldn't be trying to dereference a short, anyway, because you dereference pointers, and shorts are not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very quick, I don't know why people wrote so much:

```
#define SIZE_ARRAY 10

void ftn(unsigned short * buffer, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0; // test
    }
}

void main()
{
    unsigned short buffer[SIZE_ARRAY];
    ftn(&buffer[0], SIZE_ARRAY);
}
```

I wouldn't take Sebastian's answer he still uses `unsigned short **buffer` which is just too complication.